# Can’t use ethernet after removing kde-plasma on debian 12

Tags: debian, networking, ethernet

Here are my system’ and interface’s details:
[image]

After connecting ethernet cable to the laptop, running `ping` gives me `ping: connect: Network is unreachable` and with `sudo apt update`, I het  `could not resolve <domain name>` errors. How do I use ethernet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `eno1` to `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eno1
   allow-hotplug eno1
   iface eno1 inet dhcp
```

edit your `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" |sudo tee -a /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then:

```
sudo dhclient eno1
```

Or use `ifup` .

Comment: `8.8.8.8` is Google's public DNS Server.  I recommend changing the nameserver entry to something on your local network(usually your default gateway), after you get everything reconnected and updated.  This allows DNS requests to be answered locally by your ISP.